# SSH Public Key Authorization error Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, amazon-ec2

I am trying to SSH onto my server with the command `ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@ip_address` as I did with no issues last week but this week it is giving me an error of only `ec2-user@ip_address:Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).` which I got before that led me to connecting to wrong server / having key in wrong file but I fixed that so I know that isn't the problem.

This is the error message I am receiving when trying to connect.

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "34.255.97.122" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 34.255.97.122 [34.255.97.122] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key1.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file key1.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 34.255.97.122:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 34.255.97.122
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KcJCcNrItmtT7CwXIEndRD42wLyphxOtQR540TzFbSk
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 34.255.97.130
debug1: Host '34.255.97.130' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: key1.pem ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: key1.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:ROAQ4zFxWIgz+DlQwSwqivDbjdPsFEh1LCmRYMc/iss
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@34.255.97.130: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any help would be appreciated as my only solution is from more experienced people.

Comment: Have you previously used Kerberos to authenticate to this host? I'm seeing unusual  Kerbero-related errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios:

1. `ssh_config` is the config file for `ssh-client`.
2. `sshd_config` is the config file for `ssh-server`.

If `sshd_config` does not exists, then to install `ssh-server`.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. I just installed the ssh-server and now can see this file. It is now unresponsive when I try to connect. Should I change the PasswordAuthentication to No and then try to connect?

Comment: I also seen on other posts that you are supposed to do this but I still don't have a .ssh file, I have a unextracted authorized_keys file and the sshd_config.

 chmod 700 .ssh
and then :

 chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
and test this :

restorecon -r -vv .ssh/authorized_keys is what I seen on other posts to do,

sshd_config is within etc/ssh and the unextracted keys are within the directory usr/share/man/man5

Comment: Is correct, the file authorized_keys into .ssh directory, must be with chmod 600, the content of id_rsa.pub located in the client it can copy and paste in the file authorized_keys in the server with  some editor such as vi or nano (it's an option).

Comment: Have updated my post with new error message. Also Edgar, I see IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa within the client file but the authroized_keys are in an extracted folder, where would I unextract too as I don't think I can nano into an unextracted file can I? Also I only have ssh directory, not a .ssh

Comment: Ahh ok. You can create it with either

Comment: I'm confused... create what in either?

Comment: I've never had this issue before and no solution seems to be working for me and I am worried of messing up the configuration of other files which will cause bigger problems...

Comment: Sorry, In the server you can create the .ssh directory manually or with the command ssh-keygen -t rsa (this command create the directory).  In the new directory create the authorized_keys file with chmod 600, into file paste the content of the id_rsa.pub file localed in the client.  Note that file name is exactly id_rsa.pub, if does not exists in the client then execute ssh-keygen -t rsa too for create the file.

Comment: Could you explain why not having the SSH server installed would make the SSH client non-functional, especially since the user says it used to work?

Comment: Yes it worked less than a week ago, I come back on to start working and all of a sudden it's just not allowing me to connect for some reason @Kusalananda

Comment: I have created the .ssh directory and I copied the authorized_keys.5 file into it along with executing the chmod 600 for read and write access. In the authorized_keys file I then pasted the id_rsa.pub content into it but even after all of that it is still saying "Permission denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)"

Comment: If you only need connect to remote hosts or send files from your host then only need ssh-client,  but if you need receive connections with or without keys or files from remote hosts then need ssh-server.  If the user says it used to work with only ssh-client, may be possible that only used it for send or connect remote hosts.

Comment: I used it for connecting to an EC2 Instance via the given IP address with port 22 and 80 open.

Comment: Are you restarted sshd service ?

Comment: @EdgarCivil I can assure you that the local `sshd` service has _nothing_ to do with this user's issue. Do not tell them to install services that they don't need. Running a possibly public-facing service such as `sshd`  will potentially make their system vulnerable.

Comment: Ok, don't problem ...

Comment: Oh well as I mentioned I don't want to be installing stuff that could give me more problems than I already have... I have restarted the server and installed what he mentioned and still not working with the same error message.. Please can anyone help?

Comment: @Kusalananda Do you have any idea why it mightn't be working even tho it did a week prior with this error message?